# added more informationMagento can't see attribute in backend

Tags: php, mysql, magento, attributes, setup-deployment

I created an attribute using this function in my module setup file:

```
$this->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'outofstock_date', array(
    'group'         => 'Inventory',
    'input'         => 'text',
    'type'          => 'int',
    'label'         => 'Out of Stock Date',
    'visible'       => 0,
    'required'      => 0,
    'user_defined'  => 1,
    'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL
    ));
```

I know that the creation of the attribute worked, because I can find it in the database using this query:

```
select * from eav_attribute where attribute_code like '%stock%';
```

However, I cannot find it in the backend. It's not appearing on the edit products page, not can I see it listed in either the attributes management screen nor the attribute sets one. What did I do wrong when creating it? Why can I not find it in the backend?

Also: the above is in the mysql4-install-0.1.0.php setup file, and the part of the config file triggering it is this:

```
    <resources>
        <giftlab_inventory_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Giftlab_Inventory</module>
                <class>Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </giftlab_inventory_setup>
    </resources>
```

Comment: Check your attribute sets manager again and try to find it in either Inventory group or on the right side unassigned.

Comment: @KalpeshMehta I did, I couldn't find it. I even tried reindexing everything (caches already disabled), still nothing.

Comment: Verify whether your setup script has run successfully..check entries in core_resource table.

Comment: entry appears in core_resource table, and like I said the attribute does get inserted. I think the problem might be with the class I'm using?

Answer (score 0):

fixed installer script:

```
<?php
    $installer = $this;
    $installer->startSetup();
    $installer->addAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'outofstock_date', array(
        'group'         => 'Inventory',
        'input' => 'date',
        'type' => 'datetime',
        'label'         => 'Out of Stock Date',
        'visible'       => 1,
        'required'      => 0,
        'user_defined'  => 1,
        'global'        => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'backend' => 'eav/entity_attribute_backend_datetime',
    ));

    $installer->endSetup();
```

have in mind, however, group will usually add another 'Inventory' group so you may end up with two, but since this question is about lack of visibility in backend, so is the answer.
try using addAttributeToGroup() maybe.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: @RomanC thank you for your comment, could you let mw know on why my answer doesn't point out the reason for his problem?